# Accessing the child of a container in android

Tags: java, android

I have a custom list adapter being populated by a database. I need to get the text from each the `TextViews` within each row when they are clicked. How do I tell the program to give me the child of the main container?

`XML` for the container:

```xml
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <View style="@style/Divider" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Year"
        android:id="@+id/textView_year_tag"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <View style="@style/Divider" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Mint"
        android:id="@+id/textView_mint_tag"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <View style="@style/Divider" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Specialty"
        android:id="@+id/textView_specialty_tag"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <View style="@style/Divider" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Mintage"
        android:id="@+id/textView_mintage_tag"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <View style="@style/Divider" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```

The class in which I am handling the clicks:

```
public class PennyFlyingEagle extends ListActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private CoinsDataSource datasource = new CoinsDataSource(this);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_blank);
        addValues();
        setUpComponents();
    }

    private void setUpComponents(){
        ArrayList<Coin> myValuesToDisplay = getDatabaseContent();
        MyCustomListAdapter adapter = new MyCustomListAdapter(this, myValuesToDisplay);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    private ArrayList<Coin> getDatabaseContent(){

        datasource.open();
        ArrayList<Coin> coins_list = datasource.getAllCoins(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_PENNY);
        return coins_list;

    }

    public void addValues()
    {
        PopulateDb makeDB = new PopulateDb(this);
        makeDB.openDB();
        makeDB.setDBPenny();
        makeDB.closeDB();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //Get the text from the TextViews
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Option 1: You can get the current clicked item view from the `view`
  param of `onItemClick` method. And then through `findViewById` you
  can get the text view and the text.
- Option 2: You can set a tag to the item in your custom adapter. In
  `getView`, you can set a tag to the return value `view`. After that, 
  you can simply get the text (e.g. "2 years") directly by calling
  `android.view.View.getTag()` on the `view` param of `onItemClick`
  method.

Answer (score 2):

Putting Sir, @Shao into practice

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//Get the text from the TextViews
String text = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textviewtoget)).getText().toString(); 
}
```

feel free to accept Sir Shao's answer..

Comment: Thank you for putting his @Better Shao's ideas into code, it helped me understand it much better